# Outlook 2010 minimize to system tray at startup

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010, boot, notification-area

I am trying to find out how to start Outlook 2010 minimized to the system tray.

There was [a .VBS script](https://superuser.com/a/578322) that someone provided on a different question regarding the same subject. The problem with said script for me was the way that it opened at startup left it lingering maximized on the desktop for 5-8 seconds before it minimized to the tray.

What I was looking for was for Outlook to open straight to the tray without having MS Outlook 2010 open maximized to the desktop. Outlook 2010 has a splash screen that opens while the program is loading plug-ins and such and then the program should go straight to the tray minimized, not opening at all. Outlook 2007 did that without a problem at all.

Comment: Can you link to the other question where you got the VBS script from? If you right-click the tray icon and select "Hide when minimized", then you can use a script to run Outlook on startup and and then simulate manually minimizing it so it goes to the tray. At best perhaps the script can be modified so Outlook starts minimized to the Taskbar, and then is minimized to the tray. This way it won't start up maximized at least, but IMO that's the best one can do.

Comment: The script has a couple of sleep(100) lines. You can try commenting those out and see if it still works with less of a delay. Otherwise as far as I can see the script can't be sped up further. Maybe someone else can suggest something though.

Comment: I'm taking it that you found the .vbs script on the other page? I wouldn't know which lines to take out. I did try changing one from Maximized to minimized and ended up with an error. If I could contact the script writer, but when I tried to comment on the page I was told that my post was deleted even though it is still there I suppose I was supposed to "ask a question" and not comment on an answer. House rules , right? Do you know script? Maybe you can tell me which ones I should try and delete to make it Min. to the tray.

Comment: Yeah, as you can see I edited your question above to link to the answer with the script. Since this is a Q&A site and not a forum, you can't post an "answer" if you simply seek clarification about something. Once you contribute and have the necessary rep (see the Privileges page for details), you'll be able to comment on any question or answer. Coming back to the script, see my comment above. Like I said, there are two **sleep(100)** lines in the script you can try commenting out/deleting. If that doesn't help I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to tell me. sleep(100) are right next to each other on the very same line. Wscript.sleep(100) are the only things on the one line. As you can see those2 things you mentioned are on the same line. I need to know exactly which lines you think I need to delete if that is ok.

Comment: Ok, guess I need to spell it out. :) There are *two* `WScript.Sleep(100)` lines. Experiment with deleting one or the other or even both and see if it helps.

Comment: I finally got the drift. First I got rid of the top one and it appeared to work but when I added it to startup and rebooted it pretty well acted the same way the script does from scratch. I also took out just the bottom and then both at the same time and it just never got to where I wanted it.I appreciate your patience with my slow "I get it" on the last answer. The way it is "as is" is not too bad except the fact that it opens on the desktop maximized for 5-8 seconds and then minimizes in the tray in Maximized mode. Very strang script. Thanks Karan.

Comment: I'm looking into some alternate methods of starting Outlook hidden, minimizing it to the tray and then un-hiding it. Haven't hit upon the magic formula so far and it's kinda slow going since I know nothing of Outlook's VBA properties/methods and need to keep consulting MSDN. *If* I'm able to cook up a better solution I'll be sure to post it below.

Comment: Thanks Karan. Just the fact that you are able to even play with code, so to say, puts you way above my pay grade. Too bad 2010 wasn't more like 2007. That was very easy to get in the tray at startup. Why MS changes their properties so much from one version to the next is way beyond me. Good luck my friend and I hope to hear good things from your efforts sometime. I guess I should just check back here or do you need to PM me?

Comment: Again, since this isn't a forum it lacks the PM system, but you can open the StackExchange menu (top-left) and configure your email settings. BTW, if you set Outlook's shortcut to start minimized and *also* [set it to run in Compatibility Mode](http://dkgadget.com/minimize-microsoft-outlook-2010-system-tray), does that make any difference at all if you start Outlook using the shortcut (and not using the VB script)?

Comment: That is the way Outlook 2007 minimized to the tray easily. Of course I tried it, first thing. Compatability mode to Vista sp2 in properties if that is what you mean. I think I have tried everything that is listed as a solution to this. You and the script were the best tries. That is why I mentioned Microsoft going backwards with their programs. 2010 should have been made easier to do things like starting it min. to the tray. I will do as you suggested with the email and keep an eye on things. I haven't given up yet.

Comment: For what it is worth, there is no point reducing the number in `WScript.Sleep(100)` (or removing the line entirely) since that is asking the script to wait for only 1/10th of a second. I tried this on Outlook 2003 and the main window appeared for no more than 2 seconds.

Comment: The reason for the SHOW_MAXIMIZED is two fold: 1. This is the way I choose to view Outlook when I'm using it and 2. If started with SHOW_MINIMIZED, the icon remains on the task bar after minimization. To improve the performance of the script, it can be added to the registry as follows:

Comment: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\ [NAME_OF_VALUE]    [REG_SZ or REG_EXPAND_SZ]    [PATH_TO_SCRIPT]

Comment: I'll see about modifying the original posting of the script (http://superuser.com/questions/467809/start-outlook-automatically-in-tray)

Answer (score 1):

I made a simple script using AutoHotKey. 
Outlook Must First Be Configured To Hide When Minimise, to do this right click on the tray icon and select Hide When Mimized.

If You Don't Know AutoHotKey Try This Compiled And Edited Version To Test. http://www.mediafire.com/download/m08a1lhmkzgq866/Minimise_Outlook.exe

---

Otherwise In AHK, Just Enter your email where it says (My Email) and change it to your directory.

```
Run, "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE"
winWait, Inbox - (My Email) - Microsoft Outlook
winMinimize
exitapp
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally do that with the built-in features of Windows and Outlook.

> Please excuse the German screen-shots. I'm in a non-Enterprise, non-MUI environment. I have added as much information as possible to ensure you can perform the tasks in an English environment.

## Outlook shortcut

- Right click on your Outlook icon and select the **Shortcut** register.
- In the **Shortcut** register go down to the option **Run:** and select the option **minimized**.
- Press **OK** to close the Outlook properties.

[image: Outlook shortcut properties]

## First start of Outlook

- When you start Outlook for the first time, right-click on the **Outlook System Tray** to bring up the options.
- Select the option **Hide, when minimized** (highlighted with a yellow border in screen shot)

[image: Outlook system tray context menu]

## Restart Outlook

- Close Outlook and wait for the system tray icon to disappear.
- Restart Outlook and enjoy Outlook minimized.

I have tested this personally on [windows-7](/questions/tagged/windows-7) with [microsoft-outlook-2010](/questions/tagged/microsoft-outlook-2010) and it works, with one limitation: Outlook starts minimized in the task bar at first.

## Workaround

- Maximize Outlook once
- Minimize Outlook once
- Outlook is in system tray